# Swagger documentation with multipart/form-data and @ApiImplicitBody

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, swagger, nestjs

I'm trying to create a controller action, which has to upload some files and saves them with some strings into the database.
For upload files I use `FileFieldsInterceptor` and for other data strings DTO. It works.
But I want document this endpoint by swagger and it doesn't work. For files, I can use `@ApiImplicitFile` with `@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')`, but for other body parameters I try use `@ApiImplicitBody` decorator and the app crashes with an error in `api-parameters.explorer.js`.

How can I document a body parameter (other than file) into `multipart/form-data` by `@nestjs/swagger` module ?

```
@Post()
@ApiOperation({ ...config.api.post })
@ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
@ApiImplicitFile({ name: 'file', required: true, description: 'Infographic file' })
@ApiImplicitFile({ name: 'file_preview', required: true, description: 'Infographic preview file' })
@ApiImplicitBody({ name: 'name', required: true, description: 'Infographic title', type: 'string' })
@UseInterceptors(FileFieldsInterceptor([
        { name: 'file', maxCount: 1 },
        { name: 'file_preview', maxCount: 1 },
    ],
    {
        storage: storageUpload('infographics'),
        limits: {
            fileSize: 20971520, // 20Mb
        },
        fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
            const mimeTypeList = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'application/pdf'];

            return mimeTypeList.some(item => item === file.mimetype)
                ? cb(null, true)
                : cb(null, false);
        },
    },
  ), new FilesValidationInterceptor())
upload(@UploadedFiles() files, @Body() createDto: CreateInfographicsDto) {
    return this.infographicsService.create(files, createDto);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad this helped you. :-) You don't need to copy parts of the answer into the question though. Instead, you can accept an answer that solved your problem or leave this question unsolved and wait until you get an answer that solves your problem. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Error

You have to use `String` instead of `'string'` for the type:

```
@ApiImplicitBody({ name: 'name', description: 'Infographic title', type: String })
                                                                         ^^^^^^
```

---

#### Form Data

Documenting form-data parameters is not yet supported by @nestjs/swagger according to this [github issue](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/issues/167). There already exists a [pull request](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/168) that would add this feature but it is not merges yet. You can subscribe to it to get notified when the status updates.

Comment: You helped eliminate the error, thanks. Now swagger generate all fields, that I need [screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/szEQFjCtGOdYzQ), but it's generate wrong request, without string field.

Comment: Request example:

curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/api/infographics" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJsb2dpbiI6ImFkbWluIiwicm9sZV9pZCI6MSwidXNlcl9zdGF0dXNfaWQiOjEsImlhdCI6MTU0NzgxMDkxOSwiZXhwIjoxNTQ3ODU0MTE5fQ.BV5h4JmsP8BYhqJuYaZpwlA_lfPd8p15YHSoLzIZVeE" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "file_preview=@768px-JavaScript_logo.png;type=image/png" -F "file=@160px-JavaScript_logo.png;type=image/png"